# Wpf datagrid does not reflect at runtime when an item is added to the DataSource

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, entity-framework-core, datagrid

The problem: A datagrid does not reflect at runtime when an item is added to the DataSource.
Note: When i click at another view and return to the view that contains the datagrid, it does reflect the added item. but this is not desirable as the view is actually regenerated which causes loss of the current state.

Datasource: The datasource is a table created in visual studio (local db) using Entity FrameworkCore.

The Code:

Datagrid showing bindings

```xml
<Grid Grid.Row="4">
    <DataGrid
        x:Name="DatagridPart"
        Grid.Row="4"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Parts, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn 
                Binding="{Binding PartId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                Header="Part No" />
            <DataGridTextColumn 
                Binding="{Binding PartDescription, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                Header="Description" />
            <DataGridTextColumn 
                Binding="{Binding PartQuantity, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                Header="Quantity" />
            <DataGridTextColumn 
                Binding="{Binding PartTag, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                Header="Tags" />
            <DataGridTextColumn 
                Binding="{Binding UserID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                Header="Added by" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Binding properties and constructor of the relevant ViewModel classes (PartViewModel, BaseViewModel and PartCommand)

```cs
private ObservableCollection<Part> _parts;
public ObservableCollection<Part> Parts
{
    get
    {
        return _parts;
    }
    set
    {
        _parts = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Parts));
    }
}

//// Construction
public PartViewModel()
{
    CreateCommand = new PartCommand(this);
    _parts = PartDataAccess.GetPart();
}
public PartCommand CreateCommand { get; }

public void LoadPart()
{
    _parts = new ObservableCollection<Part>(PartDataAccess.GetPart());
}

public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
       PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new 
       PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class PartCommand : BaseCommand
{
   private readonly PartViewModel _viewModel;
   public PartCommand(PartViewModel viewModel)
   {
      _viewModel = viewModel;            
   }
   public override void Execute(object? parameter)
   {          
      PartDataAccess.AddPart(_viewModel.PartIdToDb, 
     _viewModel.PartDescription, _viewModel.PartQuantity, 
     _viewModel.PartTag, _viewModel.UserIdToDb);

     _viewModel.LoadPart();
   }            
}
```

Method to retrieve data from the database.

```cs
public static ObservableCollection<Part> GetPart()
{
    using (var db = new MikeInventoryContext())
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<Part>(db.Parts.ToList());
    }
}
```

DataContext set in the code behind:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PartViewModel partViewModel = new PartViewModel();
        this.DataContext = partViewModel;
    }
}
```

Note: I have shown a very small portion of the code for clarity. If more information is needed, I will be delighted to provide them.

What I have Tried:

I have created a collection to serve as the database, and connected it to the datagrid using the same properties and bindings. It works fine.

```cs
public static ObservableCollection<Part2> _DatabaseParts = new ObservableCollection<Part2> 
{ 
    new Part2(){PartId=100, PartDescription = "Plier", PartQuantity = 12, PartTag = "Plier", SupplierId = 100, UserID = 101}, 
    new Part2(){PartId=101, PartDescription = "Spanner", PartQuantity = 12, PartTag = "Spanner", SupplierId = 100, UserID = 102}
};

public static ObservableCollection<Part2> GetPart2()
{
    return _DatabaseParts;
}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. There is no need to tell us how long you are searching for a solution and/or how desperate you are about that. Just ask your question.

Comment: Where is the part where you update the data? There is no magic update when you add/update data. You have to do that by yourself

Comment: I have tried a separate method e.g LoadPart() which will be called in the execute method. it runs after the data is added and feeds the result to _parts property. I have tried this on one of the solution iteration, I could see that the _parts and Parts contain the new data but it does not reflect on the datagrid. I did notice at the time that the setter on the Parts property is skipped each time the code runs, I dont know why this is and if this is the problem. I will edit the post to show this LoadPart() method. in the meantime, you can let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Is your viewmodel definitely : inotifyproprtychanged?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing data access in the vm ctor.  I usually have a task gets the data. Construct the vm then await the get data task.

Comment: Hi Andy, thank you for your time. The viewmodel Inherits from the BaseVIewModel which implements InotifyPropertyChanged. I will add this to the code above for clarity.

Comment: Hi Andy, you are right. the GetPart() method is actually located at a separate Namespace(Folder) called DataAccess. I intend to the the SCRUD operation there, I just need to get this working, I can refactor later. Thank you for your time and I look forward to your assistance if you have the time, i really do appreciate!

Comment: If Execute() is the method you call to dynamically update the Parts collection then what is the _viewModel variable?  It looks like you must replace `_viewModel`with `this`  in order to operate on the correct instance that is the binding source for the control..

Comment: Additionally, in LoadPart() you must assign the new collection to the property and not the backing field. The property raises the change event and not the field. Replace `_parts` with `this.Parts`.

Comment: *"A datagrid does not reflect at runtime when an item is added to the DataSource."* - Why don't you show that part?

Comment: BionicCode, you are a Star. you have solved my problem. The issue was that I was assigning the new collection to the private field "_parts" instead of to the "Parts" property. Regarding your other points, the _viewModel is a field of the PartViewModel which I used to assign the properties to the AddPart() as arguments. The AddPart() adds the newly created Part to the DB which is retrieved afterwards with the GetPart() and the LoadPart(). I will edit the code and post it as an answer so others in the future can see the correction made and learn from my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See solution here:
The problem arises from this line of code in the `LoadPart()` method:

```
_parts = new ObservableCollection<Part>(PartDataAccess.GetPart());
```

The private field `_parts` should be replaced with the public Property `Parts` or `this.Parts`. The correct code will now be:

```
this.Parts = new ObservableCollection<Part>(PartDataAccess.GetPart());
```

Many thanks to you all for the assistance!

Comment: **1.** `PartDataAccess.GetPart()`already returns an `ObservableCollection<Part>`. **2.** If you only change the whole collection you do not need an `ObservableCollection` at all, any collection would do the job with less overhead

Comment: Sir Rufo, yes you are right, the only reason I had the LoadPart() method is so I can link the GetPart() with the Part creation process, this now made things more complicated than it needs to be and add resource cost. I will look at refactoring the code base so the same result will be achieved with less. your assistance is very much appreciated -  Michael

Comment: You should also think about using a MVVM framework like ReactiveUI where you can eliminate such failures by design. Declaring the property `Parts` is reduced to `[Reactive] public ObservableCollection<Part> Parts { get; private set; }` and as you can see, you only have a property and no underlying field you can write to ;o) - But in fact those frameworks do a lot more than this which you can see in their [compelling example](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/getting-started/compelling-example)

Comment: Fantastic suggestion, the example looks very clean from just reading it. It eliminates my mistake, reduce the chance of runtime error, memory leaks and offers more. I will look more into the example you provided and other similar framework. I have heard about the MVVM toolkit but I wanted to write all the code myself so I can better understand the design and Implementation of the MVVM pattern.  I will try one of those on a future project, thank you very much, your assistance has been immense!

Comment: To push you more forward on your journey you should also have a look at [nuget: Wpf.Extensions.Hosting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Wpf.Extensions.Hosting#readme-body-tab) which is very helpful for IoC. A very short example with everything together can you find [here](https://github.com/SirRufo/so-DatePicker). But be careful, just one step after the other ;o)

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be just a typo in this portion of code. You specified the wrong type name to the OnPropertyChanged notify function.

```
public ObservableCollection<Part> Parts
{
    get
    {
        return _parts;
    }
    set
    {
        _parts = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Part));
    }
}
```

Change

```
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Part))
```

to

```
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Parts))
```

Edit: Clarity

Comment: Thank you for spotting that,I do appreciate your time and your assistance. I must have typed that wrongly while asking the question, in the code, it is actually OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Parts)); please let me know if you need more information so you can be in a better position to help.